# what is the impact of rails 2.3's rack support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

Does it make any difference in terms of developing Rails apps now that it uses rack to talk to web servers?  Should we do anything differently to take advantage of it?  Is it just cleaner or does it have any performance improvement over the cgi implementation?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell it's mostly for simplification.

[Here's a good article though.](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2009/02/its-only-rack-on-rails-but-i-like-it/)